# Convert HAML to ERB/HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-conversion

I'm looking for a reliable program to convert a HAML template to an equivalent ERB/HTML template.

---

The question was [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/967262/395857) by Karlas Furecz on SO but was closed and deleted.

Answer (score 0):

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18398050/395857) from [user2710230](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2710230/user2710230):

I recommend you to use [HAML2ERB](https://haml2erb.org/) service. It's really cool and generates valid ERB/HTML code! The benefits are:

1. HTTPS - if you need some security for your markup;
2. API - you could write the plugin or something else for your IDE;
3. Simple - just put your HAML code to the textbox and click "Convert";
4. Project is active - the author is currently working on it.

Project was tested on big HAML views (over 800 lines of markup) from the real production app and it worked fine for me.